# MySQL - Display output columns one below the other with a different heading other than the column names

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the below SQL on mySQL

```
SELECT t1.U_COUNT AS U_COUNT, t2.R_COUNT AS R_COUNT 
FROM 
(
SELECT SUM(TRP_COUNT) AS U_COUNT 
FROM `SAL_TAB` 
WHERE CUST='SS' AND TV_POS='VFG' 
) t1,
(
SELECT SUM(TRP_COUNT) AS R_COUNT 
FROM `SAL_TAB` 
WHERE CUST='SS' AND TV_POS='FHT'
) t2;
```

the output I get is

```
+---------+---------+
| U_COUNT | R_COUNT |
+---------+---------+
|      56 |      67 |
+---------+---------+
```

The output I'm after is,

```
+------------+-------------+
| SALES_TYPE | SALES_COUNT |
+------------+-------------+
| U_COUNT    |          56 |
| R_COUNT    |          67 |
+------------+-------------+
```

I spent a lot of time now trying to figure this out but haven't been able to. Could someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'U_COUNT' as SALES_TYPE,SUM(TRP_COUNT) AS SALES_COUNT 
FROM `SAL_TAB` 
WHERE CUST='SS' AND TV_POS='VFG' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'R_COUNT' as SALES_TYPE,SUM(TRP_COUNT) AS SALES_COUNT 
FROM `SAL_TAB` 
WHERE CUST='SS' AND TV_POS='FHT'
```

Comment: Thank you Madhivanan. Brilliant stuff.